# Swift Add square dashes to Circle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a custom view class which draws a circle as it is seen below:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RotaryCircleSlider:UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue
        {
        didSet { print("mainColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = UIColor.orange
        {
        didSet { print("bColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 4
        {
        didSet { print("ringThickness was set here") }
    }

    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn:rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        if (isSelected) { drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: rect) }
    }

    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect)->()
    {
        let hw:CGFloat = ringThickness/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: hw,dy: hw) )
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

However I want the circular view to be divided like a clock.

Although, I tried **linecap** and **lineDashPattern** I could not get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that will create your desired view... you can alter them according to your design

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RotaryCircleSlider:UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1999788582, green: 0.2000134587, blue: 0.1999712586, alpha: 1)
        {
        didSet { print("mainColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7466413379, green: 0.027390128, blue: 0.2014107406, alpha: 1)
        {
        didSet { print("bColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 14
        {
        didSet { print("ringThickness was set here") }
    }

    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn:rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        let ringView = RingProgressHud(frame: rect)

         drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: rect)
          addSubview(ringView)

        let stack = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width * 0.4, height: rect.width * 0.4))
        stack.alignment = .center
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        addSubview(stack)


        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "172"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .heavy)
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.textColor = .white

        let move = UILabel()
               move.text = "Total Move"
               move.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
               move.sizeToFit()
               move.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5293634534, green: 0.5294427276, blue: 0.529346168, alpha: 1)

        let ccw = UILabel()
                      ccw.text = "CCW"
                      ccw.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .semibold)
                      ccw.sizeToFit()
        ccw.textColor = .white

        let direction = UILabel()
                      direction.text = "Active Direction"
                      direction.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
                      direction.sizeToFit()
                      direction.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5293634534, green: 0.5294427276, blue: 0.529346168, alpha: 1)


        stack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(move)
         stack.addArrangedSubview(ccw)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(direction)

    }

    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect)->()
    {
        let hw:CGFloat = ringThickness/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: hw,dy: hw) )
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

and other class creating clock shape bars is here

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class RingProgressHud : UIView {
    let numberOfTeeth = UInt(60) // Number of teetch to render
    let teethSize = CGSize(width:2, height:15) // The size of each individual tooth
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer() // The teeth shape layer

    private func getPathMask(size:CGSize, teethCount:UInt, teethSize:CGSize, radius:CGFloat) -> CGPath? {

        let halfHeight = size.height*0.5
            let halfWidth = size.width*0.5
        let deltaAngle = CGFloat(2*Double.pi)/CGFloat(teethCount); // The change in angle between paths

        // Create the template path of a single shape.
        let p = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: -teethSize.width*0.5, y: radius, width: teethSize.width, height: teethSize.height), transform: nil)
        let returnPath = CGMutablePath()

        for i in 0..<teethCount { // Copy, translate and rotate shapes around
            let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: halfWidth, y: halfHeight)
            let rotate = translate.rotated(by: deltaAngle*CGFloat(i))
            returnPath.addPath(p, transform: rotate)

        }

        return returnPath.copy()
    }

    private func commonSetup() {

        shapeLayer.path = getPathMask(size: frame.size, teethCount: numberOfTeeth, teethSize: teethSize, radius: ((frame.width*0.4)-teethSize.height))
        shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411435485, green: 0.3411974311, blue: 0.341131866, alpha: 1)
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonSetup()
    }
}
```

[image]

i also added them on git ... you can download them from there as well

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/jwd-ali/75f9c7e185d545a7df1047103cb7e8a7)

Comment: Sir, when trying on ipad or bigger screen sizes the outer ring does not and inner one conflicts, is it possible t o make it dynamic?

Comment: what size you are trying ?

Comment: Iphone 11 Pro Max or Ipad Air

Comment: size ? like 400x400 or 200x200

Comment: yes on bigger screen sizes their size do not work in parallel.Especilly the height of inner circle

Comment: Give me size sir .... what size are you assigned? Give me view height width

Comment: For example 1080 x 810 ipad, Additionally you san see the pictıres below in the link sir

Comment: I did not give a specific size to view, initally I assigned a 260x260, but it autoresizes according to screen size

Comment: give it a proper auto resizing contraint ... that its height always equal to its width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208560/discussion-between-jawadali-and-habil-ganbarli).